# Connect to Watson DiscoveryService through a proxy using .net/c#

Tags: c#, .net, http-proxy, watson-discovery

Can't connect to Watson Discovery Service while behind a corporate proxy, using C#

I read the documentation, and searched online but only a reference to a NodeJS based implementation. There was also someone looking for a solution to the same problem but using Java, and what was proposed was to extend the current api to add a method to support proxy.

```
 IamAuthenticator authenticator = new IamAuthenticator(
     apikey: "{apikey}"
     );

 DiscoveryService discovery = new DiscoveryService("2019-04-30", authenticator);
 discovery.SetServiceUrl("{url}");

 var result = discovery.CreateEnvironment(
     name: "my_environment",
     description: "My environment"
     );

 Console.WriteLine(result.Response);
```

The code above comes straight for the documentation and it works fine, as long as I'm not behind a proxy. 
I want to know if I'm missing something or Watson .net SDK doesn't support proxies. I already asked in IBM developer forum but no answers.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to set proxies argument? This is the python version, but maybe

```py
proxies={'proxies.https' : 'your_proxy', 'proxies.http' : 'your_proxy'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set the proxy via `http_proxy` or `https_proxy` environment variable. You can set this in the application environment using

```
set http_proxy=http://proxy.server.com:3128
```

from cmd.

You can also set this in the application using

```cs
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("http_proxy", "http://proxy.server.com:3128");
```